# Was Quirrell the Defense against the Dark Arts teacher for more than one year?

Tags: harry-potter, defence-against-the-dark-arts

It's well seen throughout the series that there is a “curse” on the DADA teacher position, that no one can hold that post for more than a year. But it seems like Quirrell has been around for longer than a year. What's up with that?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Quirrell was the *Muggle Studies* teacher, prior to his travels. Once he met Voldemort in Albania, he returned (for Harry's first year) as Defense Against the Dark Arts teacher, (failing to last more than a year).

For confirmation, see [this JK Rowling interview at *The Leaky Cauldron*](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/7/30/j-k-rowling-web-chat-transcript):

> **Has the jinx on the DADA teaching post at hogwarts been lifted?**
>
> Yes, at last! Incidentally, I know some have asked about Quirrell with regard to this question.
>
> He was teaching at Hogwarts for more than a year, but NOT in the post of DADA teacher. He was previously Muggle Studies professor.

Comment: There is a subtle reference that ever since Voldemort was rejected the post of DADA teacher, he jinxed the position and no one has held it for more than 1 year.

Comment: @Swanand Additionaly, J.K.Rowling confirmed herself that the position was jinxed by him: "... of course, the jinx is broken now because Voldemort's gone. Now they can keep a good Defense Against the Dark Arts teacher." _[Today Show, 26 July 2007](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0726-today-vieira1.html)_

Answer (score -3):

As I explained in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/204860/100430), Quirrel was apparently the Defense Against the Dark Arts teacher for more than a year. As for how it fits with the curse on the position, I explained there that there probably was no such curse.

Comment: Even given that Rowling herself has stated that there was?

Comment: @MattGutting See the discussion starting [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48929982#48929982).

Comment: -2 for blatant contradiction with word of god.

Comment: @Gnemlock -2 to the god for (not so blatant) contradiction with the books.