# Why did Hogwarts hire DADA teachers?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, albus-dumbledore, defence-against-the-dark-arts

Dumbledore knew that Voldemort had cursed the Defence Against the Dark Arts teaching position. So, hiring DADA teachers is knowingly putting their lives at risk. Did Dumbledore make a mistake by continuing to hire DADA teachers?

Comment: *Somebody* had to teach the class, right?

Comment: I never got the impression that Dumbledore **knew** the post was cursed - saying you 'curse' something and actually putting a hex on it are two wildly different things.

Comment: @Zibbobz i agree, the curse always seemed speculative/rumored i thought. I never remember if they stated it was for sure cursed, plus im unsure if a curse like that is even possible, cursing a titled position? would simply changing the position alleviate said curse, calling it practical study of person defense in relation to the dark arts, and various magical creatures. lol

Comment: Based on answers [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/10563/5184) and [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/40776/5184), the consensus is that it *was* cursed, but Dumbledore was speculating based on anecdotal evidence.

Comment: The question here is rather "Why was DADA still thaught?" No?

Comment: &ThomasDB Yeah  kind of.Hiring a professor was at great risk to their personal safety.Like Lupin getting exposed as a werewolf, the original Mad-Eye getting locked in a trunk.Snape suffered damage to his reputation after his year.

Comment: As ZenLogic's answer points out, the only teacher to die while working as the DADA teacher was Quirrell, the guy *possessed by Voldemort*. And if the Dark Lord is returning, don't you think it's a good idea to teach people to defend themselves?

Comment: I understand cursing physical things like objects, places, and people.  But how do you curse a metaphorical concept like a position?

Comment: @cde In a universe where it is possible to curse people and objects, this shouldn't come as too much of a surprise.

Comment: @Default no, it does. Because attaching (magical) energy to a physical object is logical. A concept being cursed is like cursing a mathematical formula like 2 + 2 = 4.

Comment: If the curse was "no more than 1 year", couldn't he simply, you know, hire them with 1-year contract?

Comment: Would magic being applied to Triwizard champions count as magic being applied to a title?

Comment: @ThomasDB: The very fact that Voldemort was able to curse the office of teacher of Defense Against the Dark Arts illustrates why the course still needed to be taught. There were people out there using the Dark Arts, and so students needed to know how to handle them.

Comment: @TheSpooniest, I'm not arguing about the necessity of DADA being thaught. Of course it had to, but this question, for me, leads to asking the question "Why is it still taught" all be it a stupid question. Because as you say and I agree fully on it, it's necessary. And thus it's necessary to hire a teacher for it. So the (original(and mine)) question is a bit moot imo.

Comment: @Default_User Snape probably suffered damage to his reputation *every* year.

Comment: Wasn't Professor Quirrell the DADA professor for multiple years (even before he went to Transylvania)?

Comment: @TylerH He was a teacher for another subject, I think muggle studies. But it was his first (and only) year of DADA when Harry started Hogwarts.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Dumbledore had a strong suspicion, though not absolute knowledge, that the post was cursed. He also guessed the reason why: in HBP he tells Harry that, after he refused the DADA post to Voldemort, he had never been able to keep a DADA teacher for longer than year. But Dumbledore seems to have discovered the curse by watching DADA teachers, year after year, be forced to leave the school.

Presumably, Dumbledore continued the DADA class for two reasons. First, it was a core requirement for students who were below N.E.W.T. level. Even after Voldemort's initial fall from power, Dumbledore expected that Voldemort would probably return one day, which would place students who could not defend themselves in serious danger. All students needed basic self-defense instruction, especially the future Aurors, whose services would be desperately needed if Voldemort came back to power. (Tonks, for instance, received her schooling and Auror training during the years the curse was operative.) The decision may also not have lain with Dumbledore alone--if Dumbledore had tried to discontinue the class, the Ministry might have gotten involved, since it would have a vested interest in ensuring that Aurors received their early training.

Second, the same observations that suggested the curse's existence to Dumbledore also suggested that the curse was primarily intended to cause problems for the Headmaster of Hogwarts. It was aimed more at Dumbledore than at the teachers themselves. For the curse to function, the DADA teacher simply had to be unable or unwilling to return to teach for a second year. Quirrell and Barty Crouch Jr. died because of their Death Eater activities (though the exact date of Crouch's death is unknown). But the curse would have been fulfilled if they had left because they suffered a persistent toothache, or disliked the students, or felt a sudden urge to play professional Quidditch. And perhaps teachers in more peaceful times--the earliest days of Voldemort's rise to power, or the first ten years of Harry's life--did leave the position for such reasons. Dumbledore only says that he hasn't been able to keep a teacher for longer than a year, but he does not suggest that every teacher left after some serious calamity. Even Lupin and Snape, who both lost their positions for reasons connected with Voldemort's return to power, suffered neither death nor serious injury during their time teaching the class. Physical and mental injuries seem to have come only to those teachers who made particularly unwise choices.

Dumbledore is a strong believer in choice. He even emphasizes to Harry in HBP that the prophecy made about him and Voldemort would not function apart from their own free will. Obviously, a curse is different than a prophecy, but I think that Dumbledore would likely emphasize the role of choice in fulfilling the requirements for a curse of this kind. Because it isn't an Imperius Curse, no DADA teacher is forced to do anything against their will. As a result, whatever forces them to leave their position at the end of the year will be a product of their own free choices--good or bad.

Comment: Good point about choice. "It is our choices that make us who we are far more than our abilities." remains one of the most memorable Dumbledore quotes.

Answer (score 23):

While Dumbledore *did* know the post was cursed, the curse does not necessarily mean that the teacher dies. The curse ensures that no teacher lasts longer than a full year in the post.

> "Oh, he definitely wanted the Defence Against the Dark Arts job. The Aftermath of our little meeting proved that. You see, we have not been able to keep a Defence Against the Dark Arts professor for more than a year since I refused the post to Lord Voldemort." (Albus Dumbledore, Half-Blood Prince)

As we know, Snape didn't die due to his post as DADA teacher. Also, Lupin did not die until 4 years after leaving this post. Lockhart, Moody (or if you remember not even Crouch died) and Umbridge all lasted out their post too. In fact, Quirrell was the only teacher of this subject to actually die whilst actually still teaching it. So Dumbledore was not condemning these wizards to die, merely hiring them knowing that he will have to do the same again with someone else next year.