# Did Barty Crouch Jr. know the Defense Against Dark Arts teacher job was cursed?

Tags: harry-potter, defence-against-the-dark-arts, barty-crouch-jr

Before Barty Crouch Jr. went to Hogwarts to become the Defense Against the Dark Arts teacher, he was already in communication with his master, Lord Voldemort. Voldemort knew the post was cursed and had several options.

- Voldemort could have lifted the curse for a year.
- He could have warned Barty Crouch Jr. about the curse.
- He could have used the curse to force his minion to obey. (He's punished other minions who failed specific tasks, such as when he punished Lucius Malfoy for failing to retrieve the prophecy.)
- He could have said nothing to see what would happen.

**Did Voldemort inform Barty Crouch Jr. of the curse?**

Even if Voldemort said nothing, Dumbledore could have informed him upon offering the job since he knew (or at least suspected) the job was cursed.

> “Was he after the Defence Against the Dark Arts job again, sir? He didn’t say …’
>
> ‘Oh, he definitely wanted the Defence Against the Dark Arts job,’ said Dumbledore. ‘**The aftermath of our little meeting proved that.** You see, we have never been able to keep a Defence Against the Dark Arts teacher for longer than a year since I refused the post to Lord Voldemort.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 20 (Lord Voldemort’s Request)*</sup></sub>

~ Albus Dumbledore in *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*

**Did Dumbledore mention anything?**

The general question is, **Is there any evidence that Barty Crouch Jr. knew the job was cursed?**

Comment: I can hardly imagine, that he didn't know, it was jinxed for a long time already. I think everybody at least slightly connected with Hogwarts must have known.

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89291/why-voldemort-sent-some-of-his-best-men-to-occupy-the-dada-job-if-he-had-cursed

Answer (score 8):

## The jinx didn't affect Barty Crouch Jr

Alastor Moody took the job of DADA teacher before the 1994 school year began, after being convinced out of retirement by Dumbledore. However, before he could start teaching, he was attacked at his own home by Crouch Jr. From Chapter 35 of *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, during Crouch Jr's confession, we learn all of this.

> "My master had found out that I was still alive. He had captured Bertha Jorkins in Albania. He had tortured her. She told him a great deal. She told him about the Triwizard Tournament. She told him the old Auror, Moody, was going to teach at Hogwarts."

And from later in the confession.

> "You needed Alastor Moody," said Dumbledore. His blue eyes were blazing, though his voice remained calm.
>   "Wormtail and I did it. We had prepared the Polyjuice Potion beforehand. We journeyed to his house. Moody put up a struggle. There was a commotion. We managed to subdue him just in time. Forced him into a compartment of his own magical trunk. Took some of his hair and added it to the potion. I drank it; I became Moody's double."

This means that although Crouch Jr masqueraded in the post for a year, it was still Moody's job, and he evidently did not have a good year of it while locked in a trunk. Conversely, although Crouch Jr met with a sticky end after his apprehension, he did succeed in completing his part of Voldemort's plan.

Voldemort didn't need to inform Barty Crouch Jr of the jinx because it affects the current holder of the position of DADA professor, which he wasn't as **Moody had accepted before he was captured, his capture being his own fate at the hands of Voldemort's jinx**.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been moved to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88245/discussion-on-answer-by-nemon27-did-barty-crouch-jr-know-the-defense-against-da)

Answer (score 3):

## Barty Crouch Jr. *likely* didn’t know.

It’s not clear if Barty Crouch Jr. knew about the curse on the Defense Against the Dark Arts teaching post, but he  likely didn’t. It’s unlikely that anyone would have told him, and having spent so long under his father’s control, it’s unlikely he’d have known about it on his own.

## The Dark Lord mightn’t know he cursed it.

Though Dumbledore confirms that the Defense Against the Dark Arts teaching post was cursed, it’s not clear that the Dark Lord actually had *intentionally* cursed it and was aware of the curse himself. Since the Dark Lord never cursed any other position that he might want to make it difficult to fill, and he put two people who would serve him in the position, it seems possible he might not have cursed it intentionally.

> “Was he after the Defence Against the Dark Arts job again, sir? He didn’t say …’
>
> ‘Oh, he definitely wanted the Defence Against the Dark Arts job,’ said Dumbledore. ‘The aftermath of our little meeting proved that. You see, we have never been able to keep a Defence Against the Dark Arts teacher for longer than a year since I refused the post to Lord Voldemort.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 20 (Lord Voldemort’s Request)*</sup></sub>

It seems entirely possible that the Dark Lord’s curse on the job was a case of unintended magic caused by anger, like when Harry exploded a wine glass because he was mad about what his aunt said.

> “It’s one of the basic rules of breeding,’ she said. ‘You see it all the time with dogs. If there’s something wrong with the bitch, there’ll be something wrong with the pup –’
>
> At that moment, the wine glass Aunt Marge was holding exploded in her hand. Shards of glass flew in every direction and Aunt Marge spluttered and blinked, her great ruddy face dripping.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 2 (Aunt Marge’s Big Mistake)*</sup></sub>

Harry didn’t actually mean to explode the glass, so it’s possible that the Dark Lord similarly was angry at Dumbledore denying him the job and his anger created the curse on it without him consciously doing it.

> “Outside in the hall, he leant against the wall, breathing deeply. It had been a long time since he’d lost control and made something explode.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 2 (Aunt Marge’s Big Mistake)*</sup></sub>

Therefore, the Dark Lord may not have realized that the job was cursed, so might not have known that there was any need to take any sort of action to prevent Barty Crouch Jr. from getting cursed. Although he didn’t care about his followers, it seems unlikely that the Dark Lord would put Barty Crouch Jr. at needless risk, since he regarded him as an intelligent and highly faithful follower - he’d consider it a waste.

> “By that time, my *faithful* servant will have rejoined us –’
>
> ‘*I* am a faithful servant,’ said Wormtail, the merest trace of sullenness in his voice.
>
> ‘Wormtail, I need somebody with brains, somebody whose loyalty has never wavered, and you, unfortunately, fulfil neither requirement.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 1 (The Riddle House)*</sup></sub>

From this, it seems unlikely the Dark Lord would want to risk having Barty Crouch Jr. get cursed without it being necessary to his success, since he considered him useful.

## If Dumbledore warned, it’d be Moody.

Barty Crouch Jr. only became Moody the day before he was to start teaching at Hogwarts. Moody was offered and accepted the position before that, and if Dumbledore warned him, it’d likely be then.

> “Wormtail and I did it. We had prepared the Polyjuice Potion beforehand. We journeyed to his house. Moody put up a struggle. There was a commotion. We managed to subdue him just in time. Forced him into a compartment of his own magical trunk. Took some of his hair and added it to the Potion. I drank it, I became Moody’s double. I took his leg and his eye. I was ready to face Arthur Weasley when he arrived to sort out the Muggles who had heard a disturbance. I made the dustbins move around the yard. I told Arthur Weasley I had heard intruders in my yard, who had set the dustbins off. Then I packed up Moody’s clothes and Dark detectors, put them in the trunk with Moody, and set off for Hogwarts.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 35 (Veritaserum)*</sup></sub>

By the time Barty Crouch Jr. became Moody, Dumbledore would probably have given the real Moody any warnings he’d wanted to, so Barty Crouch Jr. wouldn’t have gotten them.

Comment: Or there was no curse at all, and Dumbledore just conflated correlation with causation.

Answer (score 1):

## If he knew, he didn't care

Barty Crouch Jr. didn't want to be the Defense Against the Dark Arts teacher, he was on a mission for Voldemort, and being teacher was just part of the disguise for that mission.

At the graveyard, Voldemort refers to him as

> one, who remains my most faithful servant, and who has already reentered my service. (GoF)

His mission was to make sure that Harry touches the portkey to the graveyard. He would not have stayed there for the next year anyway, so the curse shouldn't matter to him.