# Why didn't Voldemort curse the headmaster's position (if he was able to curse the DADA teacher position)?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, albus-dumbledore, defence-against-the-dark-arts

If Voldemort was able to curse the DADA teaching position, why didn't he (or wasn't able to) curse the headmaster position? that could have helped him get Dumbledore out of his way for applying for position once again next year.

Comment: Maybe the headmaster's position somehow had more magical protection, which Hogwarts couldn't afford (or didn't bother) to give *every* member of staff?

Comment: I think this would answer your question http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/42993/54568     @rand al'thor you even edited the answer :P

Comment: @VanjaVasiljevic Aha! I was *sure* it was a duplicate, just couldn't find the other question!

Comment: Pure speculation, but it might only be possible to curse a job position that isn't currently occupied.