# Why didn't Voldemort use the "Position" curse to destroy the ministry?

Tags: harry-potter

This question [Why didn't Voldemort curse the headmaster's position (if he was able to curse the DADA teacher position)?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116529/why-didnt-voldemort-curse-the-headmasters-position-if-he-was-able-to-curse-th) discusses the reason why Voldemort may or may not have wanted Dumbledore to lose the Headmaster job.

However, for functioning of any organization a leader is required. Their are several important posts in the ministry such as Heads of Magical Law Enforcement, Auror Office, International Magical Co-operation and ofcourse the Minister of Magic.

Constant change at the top is not helpful for the Magical Community and it has been repeatedly shown that Voldemort couldn't care less for the Statute for Secrecy if it helped him.

So why didn't Voldemort use this curse to cripple the working of Ministry?

Additionally, Could this have also worked for secret organizations? Such as the Head of Order of the Phoenix?

Comment: The other question is arguably a duplicate.

Comment: Do we know if Voldemort actually had any control when he cursed the DADA position, or was it some bout of accidental rage magic that he and Harry seem to be so prone to?

Comment: @DisturbedNeo Whether or not he had control, the curse was not placed so he could control the school, it was placed because he was angry at Dumbledore.

Comment: Yeah of course, but what I meant was if he didn't have any control over that particular magic, he wouldn't be able to just curse a ministry position any time he wanted to.

Answer (score 3):

**Why would he?**

Think about it.  If he cursed the Minister's position, the Ministry would just keep coming up with bad people to do the job (although not many could be worse than Fudge) until Voldemort took control of the Ministry.  And when he takes control, the curse is still there - and whoever Voldemort put in the Minister's job would also be cursed.

If I were Voldemort, I would want to keep Fudge as the Minister for as long as I possible could.

But why didn't he curse lower-level offices?  For the same reason, with the added effect that cursing these would not help him in any way.  His curse on the DADA position didn't, in the long run, help him do anything in terms of winning the war.  He cursed that position out of spite, out of anger at Dumbledore, not to help him win the war.  Not only would it have no benefit toward him winning to curse the ministry (in fact it would hurt him), he probably didn't even think of it.

Answer (score 2):

Voldemort was more interested in molding the young minds and controlling the next generations directly by being a teacher instead of the actual authority. even when he came back to life and even after his return was no longer a secret he never became minister. He doesnt care about titles but the actual Power behind these titles. Why be prime minister or a headmaster when he can have his minions do the dirty work while he lounges in his manor with his snake! why be burdened with paper work and interviews and other job roles when he can do what he wants and need not bother with the unnecessary responsibilities. Thats why!

Comment: I think the fact that he wanted to control the ministry rather than destroy it is the salient point here.