# Why didn't Dumbledore do anything to lift the curse on the Defence Against the Dark Arts teacher?

Tags: harry-potter, defence-against-the-dark-arts

Throughout the entire series, it was rumored that there is a jinx on the post of "Defence Against the Dark Arts" teacher, which leads to the fact that, no wizard can hold that post for more than 1 year. This curse was cast by Lord Voldemort.  If Dumbledore knew the existence of this curse, why didn't he do anything to lift the curse?

Comment: See https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/173292/if-dumbledore-knew-that-the-defense-against-the-dark-arts-position-at-hogwarts-w?rq=1; which was closed as a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40776/how-did-the-curse-on-the-dada-job-work