# How did Percy Weasley know who Professor Quirrell was if no Defense Against the Dark Arts teacher has lasted for more than a year?

Tags: harry-potter

Is it possible for Quirrell to have been in the DADA teacher for more a year?
Could this be because he had Voldemort sticking out the back of his head?

Answer (score 1):

As per [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3277/was-quirrell-the-defense-against-the-dark-arts-teacher-for-more-than-one-year) question, Prof. Quirrel was previously the Muggle Studies teacher. This easily enough explains Percy's recognition of him. Whether or not he took Muggles Studies, a top-level student (and top level suck-up) like him would of course know of all the staff at Hogwarts.